# how to center slides in bxslider, so no slides are cropped

Tags: jquery, css, slider, centering, bxslider

Please take a look at the current site I'm developing: http://debourg-dev.ch/eliterent/ For the bottom brand logo slider, I am using bxslider. I'm wondering if there is a way to center the slides (logos) and to prevent bxslider from 'half showing' logos, because depending on the resolution viewing it, sometimes it shows a cropped logo if it can't fit them all into screen. Ideally I would only like it to display the logos in full that can fit into the current window.

Many thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's easy enough to center each image in its `li` by adjusting removing this:

```
.bx-wrapper img {
    display: block;
}
```

and adding this:

```
.bx-wrapper li {
    text-align: center;
}
```

But I think you are out of luck regarding the cropping issue. I was going to suggest setting a % width on the `li`s, but that sets them in relation to the `ul` which is very wide, so that won't work. You could probably do it with JS, though.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get rid of the cropping and to have the slides fit no matter the resolution, you need to know the slide width and margin, then you can calculate maxSlides using the width of bxslider container.

```
Math.floor($('#container').width() / (slide_width + slide_margin));
```

[See working example](http://jsfiddle.net/bvec9n9r/)

Comment: I was in the same boat and then I found this...which works but you have to refresh the page every time you resize the page...which works ok, but with an iPad or something that can change it's screen resolution as you turn it, it would be better if I could just resize the browser to see the changes...is there a way to adjust this code so it can function that way?

Comment: You can use viewport-relative units of measurement in CSS.